# Hover over an html table cell and have an image pop-up using javascript while hovering over it and disappear when the cursor is moved away

Tags: javascript, html, hover

Note: I am new to stack overflow and web development, web stuff is not my cup of tea.

I want to be able to hover over certain cells in an html table and have an image I have stored to pop-up, but this table is dynamically created.

Here is the javascript code that goes to a function that I already have that successfully changes the mouse pointer when hovered over; I want to be able to also have an image pop-up as well as the mouse pointer:

```
var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
var newText = document.createTextNode(name);
newCell.onmouseover = function(){hover1(this);}
newCell.appendChild(newText); //Adds to table

//Now to the hover1() function:
function hover1( row ){
row.style.cursor = "crosshair"; //Works as it should
//row.style.backgroundImage = "url('Testpic.jpg')"; <--Not Working
//row.style.color = "red"; //Also works
//Need picture to show up
}
```

Comment: Is that image stored in the same folder as your HTML file?

Comment: The html code is in the same file, I know this works with php
    <img src="<?php echo base_url('Pic.jpg'); ?>" />
I was under the impression that url() would be the same for javascript.

Comment: are u fixed with javascript or jquery is fine for you?

Comment: I've used a little bit of jquery but I really wanted to be able to do it in that function, I figured since I could change the mouse pointer like a wanted I would be able to bring up a picture like that as well but I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to make a hidden image.

```
<img src="file.path" style="visibility:hidden" id="img1">
```

And then your function can just have a line:

```
document.getElementById('img1').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for but it definitely gives me other ideas and a backup proposal, thanks. I'm brand new here I would upvote you for the help but I apparently need more reputation :(

Comment: Could you be more descriptive on what you want?

Comment: I'll have to change my layout if I must, but really I want to know if there is a way for me to load an image on the hover the same way that I change the mouse pointer in that function. I need a specific image for each cell on my table so if I did the invisible way (which is nice) it seems I would need to load hundreds of images and have them be invisible on the page, but then again I'm new to web development so I could be wrong here.

Comment: You are going to end up running into a problem. Since you are using images which I am guessing are on your computer, you will have to have the page load the images at some point in time. You could possible do some fancy coding with a client side language like Javascript that could chose what files based on hover, but the code for this will probably get messy and will be hard to understand. If you want to go this path I wish you the best of luck, but since you are just starting out I don't really recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, yeah this is something extra I wanted to do. I figured I would give it a shot but it's not necessary for me so I think I'll throw it to the side for now.

Comment: Oh, I just though of another option but you will have to change it to fit your needs. Using CSS you can specify a hover class like `td:hover` which will allow you to add CSS for when you are hovering over an object. You could then specify a background image and hide the text or something. Its just an idea.

Comment: Ok, I may look into that. Thanks for the help friend.